# Good source material for building a Kobold empire?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, campaign-development

The game I'm currently running is starting to go up in scope and one thing I'm really looking forward to doing is introducing an empire of Kobolds. Are there any good books on what these would look and work like?

I've heard of "Kobolds of Golarion", is it any good? Does it work for 3.5e, since I think it's a Pathfinder book?

I'll expect my PCs to have to travel through this empire looking for a dungeon location, so it'll be mostly a chance for them to experience what Kobold life is like, and to set the stage for later adventures in the area.

Comment: Possibly helpful review: http://www.playunplugged.com/2013/07/review-kobolds-of-golarion/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Mongoose Publishing

Excerpts from [Mongoose Publishing](http://www.mongoosepublishing.com/):

**[Slayer's Guide to Kobolds](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/1829/Slayers-Guide-to-Kobolds?it=1)**

> Kobolds are a common sight in many campaign worlds; deemed by most adventurers to be a minor nuisance at best. Certainly, most experienced adventurers would question the need to study kobolds in any great depth, but then, few have faced the full might of a kobold clan and lived long enough to warn others of the peril they offer. The Slayer’s Guide to Kobolds offers insight to all adventurers in the culture and society of this vicious race, enabling them to track down, engage and wipe out dozens of these murderous beasts. It can only be hoped that such efforts will be enough to stall and drive back a race that is, almost literally, numberless.
>
> No race in any campaign world, however, exists solely to provide cannon fodder for allegedly heroic adventurers. The Slayers Guide to Kobolds redresses this imbalance by giving Games Masters the information they need to make kobolds a solid and coherent part of their campaign. No longer will players merely scoff and draw their swords when they meet a group of kobolds within some ancient ruin. Finally, kobolds will have the respect they have always deserved.

**[The Quintessential Kobold](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/2807/The-Quintessential-Kobold?term=quintessential%20kobold&it=1)**

> Whether you are a Games Master who wants to add depth to his monsters or a player wishing to try something a little different, the Quintessential Kobold contains all you will need to expand on one of the most widely used monsters in the d20 universe. 1st level adventurers beware; the kobolds are about to bite back Cowardly, dog faced and weak! You think you know the kobold? Think again! For years low-level adventurers have wondered the deep dark searching for treasure in hidden vaults. Their main adversary has been the kobold, the lurking dweller in the depths. These savage creatures must rely on sheer weight in number to vanquish even the weakest foe and then celebrate by consuming the flesh of their enemies. That is, until now…
>
> The Quintessential Kobold contains a wealth of information detailing kobold history, traditions, resources and magic. Expand the depth of this tenacious enemy and learn of the four kobold ancestors, who set very different rules for generations to follow. Play as a hardy kobold guardian, sly harrier or even a festering rat brother, the choice is yours. Inside are a wealth of character concepts and prestige classes to choose from including dragon shadow, awakener and master of the pit.
>
> Learn to use equipment such as the dragon breather and master new kobold fighting techniques like the Knee-Cutter. Those with a more magical bent can learn how to use the dread power of blood magic but beware; to raise the power of blood comes at a high price. Never before has the kobold been covered in such detail, no longer will he act as slave and underdog. Look out, for the kobolds are about to rise, and they are thirsty for revenge.

## Bards and Sages Publishing

**[Koboldnomicon](http://www.bardsandsages.com/koboldnomiconsample.pdf)**

An excerpt from [Bard's and Sages Publishing](http://www.bardsandsages.com/):

> Though every DM’s favorite low-level opponent for their starting adventures, there is no reason why a kobold cannot be a player character. The general evil alignment of kobolds can be more a matter of circumstances than innate nature. After all, as one of the smallest and physically weakest of the dark-dwelling races, their viciousness and evil actions could be construed as more a matter of survival than as pure unadulterated evil.

## Wizards of the Coast

Excerpts from [Wizards of the Coast](http://company.wizards.com/):

**[Races of the Dragon](http://www.rpg.net/reviews/archive/12/12164.phtml)**

**Kobolds**

> Kobolds are meticulous creatures with sorcery in their blood, a variety of reptile with a strong work ethic.

- **A Day in the Life**

> Ixen opened the satchel and looked inside. Within was an egg she had laid, a dragonwrought egg, a blessing bestowed on some female kobolds.

- **Appearance**

> Kobolds are short, reptilian humanoids with bony frames and small tails. They stand approximately 2 to 2-1/2 feet tall and weigh 35 to 45 pounds.

- **Psychology**

> Kobolds exist in a world much larger than they are, dwarfed by creatures usually at least three or four times their physical mass.

- **Kobold Life**

> Kobolds are ingrained with certain behaviors. Subterranean and insular, kobold culture has had little infl uence from the outside. Nevertheless, kobolds have habits similar to those of other humanoid races.

- **Society & Culture**

> Kobold society is strongest when work is abundant.

- **Kobolds and Other Races**

> Kobolds dislike other humanoid races. They are isolationists who see others as a threat, and they surround their lairs with traps to keep outsiders at bay.

- **Religion**

> Kobolds have no time for organized religious ceremonies, but they are pious despite
>   their preoccupation with work.

- **History & Folklore**

> Finding traces of ancient kobold settlements has always been difficult. When kobolds exhaust the resources of a mine, they abandon it, taking everything of value with them.

- **Language & Settlements**

> Kobolds speak a version of Draconic, inherited directly from true dragons.

- **Creating Kobold Characters**

> The moment a kobold accepts her physical weakness, the more powerful she can become through means other than brute force.

**[Monster Manual](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/078692893X)**

> Kobolds are short, reptilian humanoids with cowardly and sadistic tendencies.
>
> A kobold’s scaly skin ranges from dark rusty brown to a rusty black color. It has glowing red eyes. Its tail is nonprehensile.
>
> Kobolds wear ragged clothing, favoring red and orange. Kobolds usually consume plants or animals but are not averse to eating intelligent beings. They spend most of their time fortifying the land around their lairs with traps and warning devices (such as
>   spiked pits, tripwires attached to crossbows, and other mechanical contraptions).
>
> Kobolds hate almost every other sort of humanoid or fey, especially gnomes and sprites.
>
> A kobold is 2 to 2-1/2 feet tall and weighs 35 to 45 pounds. Kobolds speak Draconic with a voice that sounds like that of a yapping dog.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest source of information on Kobolds and their societies in 3.5 is the book *[Races of the Dragon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786939133)*. The Kobold chapter is 18 pages long, and has the following sections:

- A Day in the Life
- Appearance
- Psychology
- Kobold Life
- Society and Culture
- Religion
- History & Folklore
- Language and Settlements

Of course, the book also includes "normal", ever-popular information on racial traits and Kobold PCs.